# LSTM same sentence in different batch predict different score when padding sequence

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm

For example, I use LSTM to make a 4-category classifer.

```
test_data = [
    'I have a flower', 
    'The stars are beautiful,because of a flower that cannot be seen.',
    'You know one loves the sunset,when one is so sad.'
]
test_gen = create_generator(test_data, batch_size=1)  # do padding
res = model.predict_generator(test_gen)
```

The sentence `I have a flower` predict score may like:

```
[0.92, 0.07, 0.001, 0.009]
```

When I let `batch_size` to 16, the predict score may

```
[0.84, 0.12, 0.02, 0.02]
```

Cause the sentence `I have a flower` is shorter than other in `test_data`, so
it was padding to the same length, and the padding item maybe is `0` or something else.
Finally, it lead to this big different(0.08=0.92-0.84 is a big number).

I just want to know: it's a normal phenomenon?
Otherwise, how to remove this uncertainty?

Comment: It is just normal to have different results if you have different batch size

Comment: So, have some track to fix this? As an important Model in AI, it's impossible to apply it to the product nakedly, right?

Comment: Not sure I understand but answering to " it's a normal phenomenon? Otherwise, how to remove this uncertainty?" the answer is 1) yes and 2) it is not an uncertainty. It is simply that using batch_size of 16 or anything else are different setups, yielding different results. There is pretty much nothing to fix here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add param `mask_zero=True` for `Embedding` or add a `Masking` layer can remove this "uncertainty", like:

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None,), dtype="int32")
x = layers.Embedding(input_dim=5000, output_dim=16, mask_zero=True)(inputs)
outputs = layers.LSTM(32)(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

[keras-masking_and_padding](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/masking_and_padding)

It can skip the padding value `0`, so the model won't learn the knowledge from the padding value `0`, and same sentence in different batch output same score.